# Python (2.7) raw_input does not response user input when another thread is running

Tags: raw-input

I have a small python server to do the following jobs:

- Main thread is getting user input using raw_input;
- Another thread (i.e. background-thread) is started by main thread to do jobs corresponding to the user input. Jobs are all written as bash script, so this thread is using subprocess.Popen to run the script.

The high-level code is like this (just abstract it because the detailed code is too long to be copied here...):

```
# A global queue is initialized to cache user inputs
command_queue = Queue.Queue()

# This is the background-thread running bash script based on user's input
class command_runner(Thread):

  def run(self):
    user_command = command_queue.get()
    # code to run bash script specified in user_command, using Popen

class main_program(object):

  def listen_user_input(self):
    command_runner.start()
    while True:
      user_input = raw_input("Please input command:")
      command_queue.put(user_input)
```

What I noticed is that when the background thread (command_runner) is running some bash script, the raw_input of main program is sometime not responding to any user input. It seems the raw_input is stuck.

Some other information which may be helpful:

- The bash scripts run by command_running are long-run but not heavy scripts (usually ~10 mins). So when the raw_input is stuck, the machine is not running out of resource.
- Some scripts may ssh to other machines, using "ssh -q some_command 2>&1" (so the ssh command is running quietly).
- All the stdout and stderr of the bash scripts are redirected to a file through "Popen(user_command, stderr=sys.stdout.fileno(), stdout=log_fp)"

Comment: Does this error persist if you add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to `Popen`? Wondering if the subprocess is inheriting Python's `stdin` and stealing it from `raw_input`

Comment: @scnerd seems your solution is working! Could you explain a bit more on this (maybe just reply so I will accept your answer~) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to your `Popen` call:

```
Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
```

By default, [`Popen` inherits its parent's file descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), including `stdin`. You're explicitly giving it a new `stdout` and `stderr`, but not a new `stdin`, which it's therefore inheriting from your main Python process. My guess is that `stdin` is getting captured by the child process (even if that process doesn't need it), preventing your call to `raw_input` from receiving the input and returning until after the `Popen` process finishes and returns control of `stdin`.

If the process might try to read from `stdin` and you don't plan to write anything to that pipe, you could also have it draw from `/dev/null` (on linux), using something like:

```
Popen(..., stdin=open('/dev/null', 'rb').fileno(), ...)
```

This would allow it to (fail to) read from stdin without hanging.